# Proof that $b^{\log_b(x)} = x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I understand that the exponential functions are inverses, and would therefore map $x$ when formed as a composition, but I cannot find any formal mathmatical proofs.
My thought process is:  $$\log_b(b^{\log_b(x)}) = \log_b(x) \rightarrow \log_b(x)=\log_b(x) \rightarrow x=x$$  Is that the only way of going about it or are there other formal proofs?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the exponential and the logarithm?

Comment: Thank you so much question provider and answer providers.  This question and the following answers were very valuable for [my article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876685/how-can-solving-left-2n-right-left-log-b-2-right-left-5n-right/4880297#4880297), and I appreciate your insight very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tautology since $\log_b(x)$ is defined as the exponent $m$ such that $b^m = x$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, if $A^x=B$, then $x=\log_AB$. Now, replace the value of *x* from the latter identity into the former.

Comment: Isn't that what I did already?

Answer (score 2):

What exponent $a$ can you put on $b$ so that $b^a=x$? $\log_b(x)$ is just the name for an $a$ that makes $b^a$ be equal to $x$. So by definition $b^{\log_b(x)}=x$.