# How Can Solving $\left( 2n \right)^{\left( \log_b 2 \right)} = \left( 5n \right)^{\left( \log_b 5 \right)}$ be Generalized for any Base of $\log_b n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The title of the question [Solving $(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861562/solving-2n-log-2-5n-log-5/4862075#4862075) asks how to solve (in some western conventions) base 10 for $(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5}$. However that question's title does not seem to indicate an arbitrary base.  For instance, one convention for "$\log$" is $\log c = \log_{10} c$.

Also the base $\log_b$ is considered there in the text. (See the referenced quote below).

How can the result for $\log_{10}$ be generalized for any $\log_b$?  Or what are the restrictions on $b$ for it to hold?

Already, algebraically it is from one of the answers that Symbolically:

$$
\boxed{
n = 
\left(
\frac{\displaystyle \left( 5 \right)^{\log_b 5}} { \displaystyle \left(2 \right)^{\log_b 2}}
\right)
^{
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}
 { \displaystyle \log_b 2 - \log_b 5 }
 }
}\tag{Eq. 5}$$

But is it true that the key identity for the reduction that $n=\frac{1}{10}$ namely the identity $\left(\log_b a\right)^c = c \left(\log_b a \right)$ also holds for arbitrary numbers $b$?  Or what are the restrictions for $b$?

If so, does that directly lead to the desired answer that:

$$
n=
\left(
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
  \right)
\right)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log_b 2 -\log_b 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
 \right)
$$
$$
\tag{Eq. 6a}
$$

$$
n=\Bigl( 1 \Bigr)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log_b 2 -\log_b 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
 \right)=\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 10}
$$
$$
\tag{Eq. 6b}
$$

As one claim in the answer for that question is, "This calculation is valid no matter what the base of the logarithm is."  But how can the algebra be simplified step-by-step to further show this is true, answering the questions here or otherwise taking a more direct route?

Comment: Raise both sides to the $\log(b)$ power to turn it into the original equation

Comment: Answer hint:  if $(2)^{\log_b 5}=(5)^{\log_b 2}$ then the term at left is $1^{\frac{1}{log_b 2 - log_b 5}}=1$.  Consider the identity $\log_b \left( \left( a^c \right) \right) = c \left( \log_b a \right)$.  Applying $\log_b$ to $(2)^{\log_b 5}$ is $\log_b ((2)^{\log_b 5})=\log_b(5)*\log_b(2)$.  Similarly $\log_b$ to $(5)^{\log_b 2}$ is $\log_b (5^{\log_b 2})=\log_b(2)*\log_b(5)$ and $(\log_b (5))(\log_b (2))=(\log_b (2))(\log_b (5))$;  so indeed $(2)^{\log_b 5}=(5)^{\log_b 2}$ and $\frac{1}{(2)^{\log_b 5}(2)^{\log_b 5}}=1$ indeed directly results in Equation 6b and the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the Questions's Equation 6a, there is a left term as follows:

$$
n=
\left(
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
  \right)
\right)*...
\tag{Question Eq. 6a}$$
And inside this left term is the quantity:
$$n_{1 L}=
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)
\tag{Answer Eq. 1}
$$
And this quantity can be simplified as:

$$n_{1 L}=
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle (5)^{\log_b 2} }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5}} 
  \right)
\tag{Answer Eq. 2}
$$

Consider from the [properties of logarithms (of arbitrary base, together with the restrictions on which numbers qualify) from this liked reference](https://www.math.wsu.edu/math/staff/cjacobs/instructor_files/cjacobs/106/PropertiesOfLogarithmsKEY.pdf):

> [image: properties of logorithims]

$$\tag{Reference Eqs. 1}$$

Since $2>0$ and $5>0$ are Real, it is possible to apply $\log_b$ at the left in the term and the term in the denominator using the following identity [from that reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4lQB.png):
$$
\log_b \left(x^p \right)=p \log_b \left( x \right)
\tag{Answer Eq. 3}
$$
It is to be tested whether $n_{1 L}=1$.  To test this hypothesis, set $n_{1 L}=1 $ and continue the necessary test by simplification as:

$$
n_{1 L}=1 \text{ implies } 5^{\left( \log_b 2 \right)}=2^{\left( \log_b 5 \right)}
\text{ implies } \log_b \left( 5^{\left( \log_b 2 \right)} \right)
                =\log_b \left( 2^{\left( \log_b 5 \right)} \right)
$$ $$
\text{ implies } \left( \log_b 2 \right)\left( \log_b 5 \right)
                =\left( \log_b 5 \right)\left( \log_b 2 \right)
\tag{Answer Eqs. 4}$$
By inspection,
$$\left( \log_b 2 \right)\left( \log_b 5 \right)
                =\left( \log_b 5 \right)\left( \log_b 2 \right)
\tag{Answer Eq. 5}$$
So clearly:
$$
n_{1 L}=1 \tag{Answer Eq. 6}
$$
From Equation 1, there is now the solution:
$$n_{1 L}=
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)=1
\tag{Answer Eq. 7}
$$
From Question Equation 6a there is now the following simplification:

$$
n=
\left(
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
  \right)
\right)*...
\tag{Question Eq. 6a}$$
$$
n=
\left(
  \left(1 \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
  \right)
\right)*...
\tag{Question Eq. 6a Simplified}$$
It is simplified since $1$ raised to any real power is $1^r=1$.
$$
n=
\left(
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log_b 5} (5)^{-\log_b 2}} 
  \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
  \right)
\right)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log_b 2 -\log_b 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
 \right)
$$
$$
\tag{Question Eq. 6a}
$$
$$
n=
\left( 1 \right)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log_b 2 -\log_b 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log_b 2-\log_b 5}
 \right)
\tag{Answer Eq. 7}$$

With the following exponential properties from [this reference link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4lQB.png) and also with the following identity:

> [image: basic log_b and inverse log_b properties]

$$\tag{Reference Eqs. 2}$$

$$
\left(\left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}\right)
^{\left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}\right)
^{\frac{\displaystyle 1}
{\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}}
=\frac{\displaystyle 1}{10}
\tag{Answer Eq. 8} $$

The [above referenced identity](https://www.math.wsu.edu/math/staff/cjacobs/instructor_files/cjacobs/106/PropertiesOfLogarithmsKEY.pdf) that $y = \log_b x \Leftrightarrow b^y=x $ basically states that $\log_b f$ and $b^f$ are inverse operations.  Also, from the [same reference](https://www.math.wsu.edu/math/staff/cjacobs/instructor_files/cjacobs/106/PropertiesOfLogarithmsKEY.pdf), $\log_b \left( c^d \right) = d \log_b c$ and the Answer Equation 8 was applied as follows:

$$
n=b^\left(
{\displaystyle \log_b} \left(
\left(
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)^{\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}
\right)^{\frac{\displaystyle 1}
              {\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}}
\right)
\right)
$$
$$
n=b^\left(
\left( \left( {\frac{\displaystyle 1}
              {\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}}
       \right)
{\displaystyle \log_b}  
\left(
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)^{\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}
\right)
\right)
\right)
$$
$$
n=b^\left(
\left( 
       \left( \displaystyle \log_b 2 -\log_b 5 \right)
       \left( {\frac{\displaystyle 1}
              {\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}}
       \right)
{\displaystyle \log_b}  
\left(
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)
\right)
\right)
\right)
$$
$$
n=b^\left(
\left( {\displaystyle 1 *}
{\displaystyle \log_b}  
\left(
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)
\right)
\right)
\text{ since }
       \left( \displaystyle \log_b 2 -\log_b 5 \right)
       \left( {\frac{\displaystyle 1}
              {\displaystyle \left(\log_b 2 -\log_b 5\right)}}
       \right)={\displaystyle 1}
$$
$$\tag{Answer Eqs. 9} $$

Now from the [Mathematics Stack Exchange Article, Proof that $ b^{\log_b(x)} = x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750709/proof-that-b-log-bx-x/750724#750724) there is the direct relationship that  $b^{\log_b(x)}=x$.  Thus applying that identity to Equations 9:

$$
\boxed{
n=b^\left(
\left( {\displaystyle 1 *}
{\displaystyle \log_b}  
\left(
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)
\right)
\right)
=
b^\left(
\left(
{\displaystyle \log_b}  
\left(
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2}
 \right)
\right)
\right)
=\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 5*2} \text{ so finally }
n = \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 10} 
}
\tag{Eq. 10}
$$